# How do I make an icon disappear on mobile?

Tags: css

Hopefully this is a simple answer.  I have a page that on desktop needs a series of share icons (fb, tw, ig) underneath a paragraph of text.  But on mobile, these icons are included in a template already so I don't need them to show.  It looks repetitive.  I am using a CMS and only have access to the body text of the page, not the headers, so extensive javascript isn't ideal.  What inline CSS styling or other such magic will make this div disappear?  And can I shrink it only on verified mobile devices or is it better to do it just with the browser window size?

Currently the code is very simple:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Some text here.
        <div id="mydiv">
            <img src="/some/icon1.png">
            <img src="/some/icon2.png">
            <img src="/some/icon3.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I need to do is make "mydiv" disappear if I'm using an iPhone, iPad, or Android device...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries:

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that limit the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color.
>
> When a media query is true, the corresponding style sheet or style rules are applied, following the normal cascading rules.

Documentation:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

For example:

```css
@media (max-width: 787px) {
  #mydiv {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
Some text here.
<div id="mydiv">
  <img src="/some/icon1.png">
  <img src="/some/icon2.png">
  <img src="/some/icon3.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!